# Exception not being caught in Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I can't seem to get my error-handling done in coroutines. I've been reading lots of articles and the [exception handling documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#exception-propagation) but I can't seem to get it working.

Here's my setup:

My `ViewModel` launches the coroutine with it's scope

```
class MyViewModel(private var myUseCase: MyUseCase) : ViewModel() {
    private val viewModelJob = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    fun doSomething() {
        uiScope.launch {
            try {
                myUseCase()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                // Do error handling here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `UseCase` just handles a few logic and in this case a validator of some sort

```
class MyUseCase(private val myRepository: MyRepository) {
    suspend operator fun invoke() {
        if (checker()) {
            throw CustomException("Checker Failed due to: ...")
        }

        myRepository.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Then my `Repository` just handles the network layer / local layer

```
object MyRepository {
    private val api = ... // Retrofit

    suspend fun doSomething() = api.doSomething()
}
```

And here's my Retrofit interface

```
interface MyInterface {
    @POST
    suspend fun doSomething()
}
```

The try/catch from the `ViewModel` can handle the error from the Retrofit call however, it can't catch the error from the `CustomException` thrown by the `UseCase`. From articles I've been reading, this should work. If I use `async` I can do `await` and consume the error but I don't have to use `async` in this case and I've been wrapping my head around this. I might be getting lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here's the error log I'm getting:

```
com.example.myapp.domain.errors.CustomException
        at com.example.myapp.domain.FeatureOne$invoke$2.invokeSuspend(FeatureOne.kt:34)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:238)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

The error directly points to the explicit `throw` statement.

Comment: `'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android'` Are you using this artifact? Basically it's specific to Android environment so that in case of crashed coroutine with unhandled exception, exception is logged before crashing Android application.

Comment: Yup. I'm using that one along with the latest version. 1.2.1 and 1.3.30 for Kotlin

Comment: Updated the question to show the stack trace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying with `CoroutineExceptionHandler` can be workaround for **handling exceptions** inside coroutines.

[CoroutineExceptionHandler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler) **context** element is used as generic catch block of coroutine where *custom logging or exception* handling may take place. It is similar to using `Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler`.

How to use it?

```
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception -> 
    println("Caught $exception") 
}
val job = GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
    throw AssertionError()
}
val deferred = GlobalScope.async(handler) {
    throw ArithmeticException() // Nothing will be printed, relying on user to call 
    deferred.await()
}
joinAll(job, deferred)
```

In your `ViewModel`, make sure that your `uiScope` is using `SupervisorJob` rather than `Job`. `SupervisorJob`'s can handle its children's failure individually. `Job` would get cancelled unlike `SupervisorJob`

If you're using `2.1.0` for AAC Lifecycle and ViewModel, use the `viewModelScope` extension instead.

Comment: I tried that too! But it's saving the exception. Next time it gets called, it just returns the same exception without executing the launch block again.

Comment: May be because of your use case? You're throwing `CustomException` anyway before calling **repo call**. It might be the case that you're getting exception every time. What about that `checker()` method?

Comment: Supposedly, the `CustomException` should be caught by the `try/catch` block in the `ViewModel`. Or am I wrong? `checker()` is just some sort of validator I use. For example, if the input is null, I throw a `NoInputException` or something. What I'm trying to achieve is to propagate the exception to the `Activity` and get the respective string from the string resources and show a dialog.

Comment: No, that's the thing !! *try/catch* block doesn't normally work in **coroutines** that way. That's why we need to pass context as `CoroutineExceptionHandler` to handle it works like `Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. The `CoroutineExceptionHandler` caught it however, once an exception is caught, that's the result everytime. Is there a way that it won't do that?

Comment: Never tried of it, so can't be sure about that. Will try and let you know soon.

Comment: It works when I use `GlobalScope` but fails if I use the `ViewModel`'s scope using `uiScope`. Docs says that `if there is a Job in the context, then Job.cancel is invoked;` I guess this is why?

Comment: Trying this would help I guess : `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)` for your uiScope.

Comment: Thanks! That made me go near the problem. I've updated the `ViewModel` code above. I was using `Job` rather than `SupervisorJob`. Changed it and it's now fixed!

Comment: Just for reference, `try-catch` around a `suspend fun` _is_ supposed to work the natural way and will catch any exceptions from the called code, and this will still work even after the coroutine was suspended and resumed. OP's failure most likely comes from improper usage of  `async-await`. If the `async` task throws an exception, this cancels the `async` coroutine, propagating the cancellation to the parent coroutine. `SupervisorJob` ignores the cancellation, but that's a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: Okay @MarkoTopolnik , so root cause is that `SupervisorJob` handles *try/catch* itself without reporting to end point from where it gets called.

Comment: No, there are two distinct mechanisms at play. One is cancellation and detecting it, and the other is exception handling. The `Job` instance is associated with a coroutine (it's in its context), but isn't directly involved in its execution. There must be explicit code that catches exceptions at the coroutine's top level and calls `coroutineContext.job.cancel()` (this code is internal to `async`). The default implementation of `Job.cancel()` in turn calls `parentJob.childCancelled()` and that's how cancellation reaches the parent `SupervisorJob`, whose `childCancelled()` is a no-op.

Comment: Now, any correctly written code will not let an unhandled exception escape the coroutine. However, users typically misuse `async-await` instead of `withContext`, unknowingly creating a sub-coroutine without exception handling, and assuming that a `try-catch` around `deferred.await()` is how they handle exceptions inside the `async` block. But that just handles the exception with which the `deferred` was completed. The `async` coroutine has already been cancelled by that time.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to resolve this would be to covert your custom error object to implement `CancellationException`

For eg:

Your `CustomException` can be implemented as :

```
sealed class CustomError : CancellationException() {
        data class CustomException(override val message: String = "Checker Failed due to: ...") : CustomError
}
```

This exception would get caught in the try/catch block of the view model

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Retrofit hasn't still created the way to mark the methods with the `suspend` keyword. You can refer it to this [link](https://zsmb.co/retrofit-meets-coroutines/). 
So the correct way of your `MyInterface` would be:

```
interface MyInterface {
    @POST
    fun doSomething(): Deferred<Response<YourDataType>>
}
```

Comment: I'm using the `2.5.1-SNAPSHOT version`. First-class support for `suspend` was added. See https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/2886

Comment: IS there any way to handle the exceptions like timeout, socket exception etc.

Comment: Yes, the confirmed answer covers that