# Android coroutines handle exception

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

In my app. I am trying to send network request using **Kotlin Coroutines**. I analyzed response and throw exception for some situation.This is the code:

```
class ProxyErrorInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        val bodyString = response.body()?.string()
        when (response.code()) {
            HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK -> {
                val error = Gson().fromJson(bodyString, BusinessModel::class.java)
                if (error.errorCode != null) {
                    throw BusinessDataException(error.errorCode, error.errorMessage)
                }
            }
            HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR -> {
                val error = Gson().fromJson(bodyString, BusinessModel::class.java)
                if (error.errorCode != null) {
                    throw BusinessDataException(error.errorCode, error.errorMessage)
                }
            }
        }
        return response.newBuilder()
                .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body()?.contentType(), bodyString)).build()
    }
}
```

This intercept exception.

```
fun getAccounts() {
    try {
        val myJob = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = interactor.getAccounts()
            launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                data.postValue(mapper.mapAccountList(response))
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("Проверка", e.message)
    }
}
```

However this didn't worked out and Finally my app crashed.

**UPDATE**

I tried use CoroutineExceptionHandler but it not helped

```
fun getAccounts() {
    val myJob = GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
        val response = interactor.getAccounts()
        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            loadingStatus.progress.set(false)
            data.postValue(mapper.mapAccountList(response))
        }
    }
}

private val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
    error.postValue(Any())
    loadingStatus.progress.set(false)
    when (exception) {
        is BusinessDataException -> {
            Log.d("Check", exception.message)
        }
        else -> {
            loadingStatus.hasError.set(true)
            loadingStatus.textError.set(exception.message)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This exception message in logcat

**06-03 17:18:01.012 23796-24010/ru.mtsbank.dbosme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: ru.mtsbank.dbosme, PID: 23796
    java.lang.Error: ru.mtsbank.dbosme.exceptions.BusinessDataException: Нарушен контракт взаимодействия, и дальше описание, что не так...
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1119)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: ru.mtsbank.dbosme.exceptions.BusinessDataException: Нарушен контракт взаимодействия, и дальше описание, что не так...
        at ru.mtsbank.dbosme.data.web.interceptors.ProxyErrorInterceptor.intercept(ProxyErrorInterceptor.kt:27)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at ru.mtsbank.dbosme.data.web.interceptors.MainInterceptor.intercept(MainInterceptor.kt:18)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:211)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)**

Comment: Refer my this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250683/10271334

Comment: I prefer `Either` over `try-catch`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `loadingStatus.progress.set(false)` is the problem. That's not getting executed in the Main Thread which might throw an exception. Whenever you are updating the UI go with `Dispatchers.MAIN` instead of `Dispatchers.Default`

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I assume this one : `data.postValue(mapper.mapAccountList(response))` is also refering to some `LiveData` or `MutableLiveData`. Please, everything that has to do with the main thread run it in the `Dispatchers.Main` context, everything else in `Dispatchers.IO`

Comment: No. I tryed remove this lines of code. Error stayed.

Comment: This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58711127/1854307 helped me